# What is the difference for pointers in the free store for user-defined objects vs. arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

Assume the following functions

```
void func (int* p);

int main(){
   int* arr = new Object[10];
   int* obj = new Object;

   func(arr);
   func(obj);
   
   return 0;
}
```

When you call the function for arr, does func() create a new pointer, p, that is a pointer to the first element of arr? And in that case, does p need to be deleted at the end of the function to prevent a memory leak?

When you call the function for obj, does func() create a new pointer, p, that needs to be deleted?

If func is now defined as `void func(int*& p)`, will it still work for arrays?

I want to ensure that I don't create accidental memory leaks when I write code

Comment: _"does func() create a new pointer, p, that needs to be deleted?"_ No, it just takes a copy of the existing pointer variable (not the values behind it!).

Comment: Q#1: The `p` parameter is pass-by-value from the callsite's provided `arr` argument.  Q#2: Assuming the policy of "raw pointers are non-owning pointers", then **no**, the `func` routine does not `delete` anything — as *ownership* is **not** being transferred.  Q#3: Same policy assumption as Q#2, and same answer: **no**.  Q#4:  **Yes**, but since the length is not being passed in as parameter, `func` will have no way to determine how big the array is, and if the `p` alias is modified, there's a leak.

Comment: When we say "delete a pointer", that is technically incorrect. The statement `delete ptr;` actually deletes what `ptr` points to, no the pointer itself. And when you pass a parameter, you just get a second pointer pointing at the same place, not a second set of heap memory.

Comment: This is not really how we do arrays anymore ("C" style pointer decay). In C++ use `std::vector<Object> arr(10);` and pass the dynamically allocated array to func like this `void func(std::vector<Object>& values)`. I think you should move to more current C++ teaching material.

Comment: `func` gets a copy of the pointer that it's called with. A pointer points at memory; copying a pointer doesn't copy the memory. So, no, you don't need to do anything extra just because you copied the pointer.

Comment: Good sources to learn cpp from are : A [recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or have a go at https://www.learncpp.com/ (that's pretty decent, and pretty up-to-date).
For C++ reference material use : [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). And after you learned the C++ basics from those sources, look at the [C++ coreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) regularely to keep up-to-date with the latest guidelines.

Comment: Just to give you a sneak peek of the "C++ core guidelines" : [avoid calling new/delete explicitly](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly). And [prefer using stl array or vector instead of "C" array](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#slcon1-prefer-using-stl-array-or-vector-instead-of-a-c-array)

Comment: you seem to confuse deleting the pointer with deleting the pointee. Colloquially when we say "delete the pointer" we actually mean "delete the pointee". When you copy a pointer no copy of the pointee is made. No matter how often you copy the pointer, you still need to `delete` the pointee only once

Comment: Um, using `new Object` for a integer pointer is going to cause some issues.

Comment: @drescherjm "*Avoid using `new`, Instead use `std::vector` and **shared** pointers from the standard library*" - *shared* should be *smart* instead :-)

Comment: A function receiving a pointer can only guarantee that the pointer is pointing to a single item, provided the content of the pointer is valid.  If you need to pass consecutive values to a function, use a container like `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no memory leak, since the function takes a pointer as an argument, inside the function you are working with the same memory area.

You should use `delete` only paired with `new`

```
               // here just creating pointer on stack which just points to the same memory block
               // but on this pointer not creating(copy) new C-array 
void func (int* p)  
{
    delete p; // If you delete an object inside the function.
              // then writing delete in main you will get an error
}


void func2 (int* p)  
{
    /* some code where we not deleting p */
}


int main(){
   int* arr = new Object[10];
   int* obj = new Object;

   func(arr);
   delete arr // ERROR: error for object 0x1f5c5080: pointer being freed was not allocated

   func2(obj);
   delete obj; // OK
   
   return 0;
}
```